# Debugging CodeStubAssembler (CSA) code in V8

Tags: gdb, v8

I am currently trying to debug some [CodeStubAssembler](https://v8.dev/docs/csa-builtins) builtins in V8.

If I understood it correctly, CSA is just fancy C++ code that efficiently generates assembly instructions for different platforms.

However, even on a debug build I can not set breakpoints with `gdb` on any code in the `builtins/*-gen.cc` files. Neither by setting a breakpoint on the file and source line, nor by trying to break on the function names. The only thing that works to get a disassembly by running `objdump -D` on the object file. But I'd like to see it while running.

Is it possible to somehow set breakpoints on the builtins generated by CSA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

V8 developer here. CSA *generates* assembly code, indeed. It does so when the `mksnapshot` binary runs as part of V8's build process. The CSA code itself is not contained in the final binary (`d8` or `libv8.so`), only its output. So the time when the CSA code runs is entirely different from the time when the generated builtins run.

The upshot is that:

- You can put a breakpoint on CSA code like on any other C++ code -- if you run the `mksnapshot` binary in your debugger (or if you compile V8 without snapshot, but that's (1) super slow on startup and (2) deprecated). You can then step through the CSA code as it emits a Turbofan IR graph which the Turbofan backend will then translate to machine code.
- You can put a breakpoint into CSA-generated builtins by putting a `DebugBreak()` instruction into the CSA code and recompiling. You can then step through the generated instructions. Note that there will be no (C++ or other) source code available, you'll have to use "layout asm" in GDB.
- If you wanted to use GDB's facilities to put a breakpoint into a CSA-generated builtin, you'd have to get its address somehow (it's possible, but cumbersome, to do that via isolate->builtins) and then put a breakpoint on the raw address where you want to break.
- Sometimes "printf debugging" is more convenient. There's `CodeStubAssembler::Print(...)` for this purpose. (Note that a plain `printf` in CSA would execute at mksnapshot time, and would not affect the generated builtin; whereas `CSA::Print` emits code into the generated builtin that will trigger an stdout-print at runtime. That's probably the most illustrative way to demonstrate the effects I tried to describe above.)

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. Could you explain on how to set to exactly get the address of the builtin using `isolate->builtins`?

Comment: `(gdb) x/2i isolate->builtins_table()[Builtins::kArrayPrototypePush] + Code::kHeaderSize - 1`; in this case it's a "trampoline": `movabs r10, 0x7f963c068f60; jmp r10`, so `x/10i 0x7f963c068f60` gives the actual builtin code and `break *0x7f963c068f60` sets a breakpoint there.

Comment: @jmrk hi, could you please provide more information about why the option `v8_use_snapshot` is deprecated although it's convenient to learn the v8 source

Comment: @hsiaosiyuan: as V8's architecture evolved, "nosnap" builds were getting ever slower to start up (making them less and less suitable for real uses) and farther away from the actually used production architecture (especially with the arrival of "embedded builtins"). It didn't make sense to continue to maintain a large amount of code complexity for a scenario that makes no sense to use in practice. You can run `mksnapshot` in gdb, it may be a minor inconvenience but it's no blocker for learning about (or debugging) V8.