# How to debug v8 builtins

Tags: c++, chromium, v8

I try [offcial site guild](https://v8.dev/docs/gdb) but encounter error. I want to debug promise constructor source code in v8 source code.

I wanted to use gdb debug v8 builtins source code. It seems that gdb can not set breakpoint in builtins.

the version of v8 if 2022

Comment: Torque adds a layer of indirection (insofar as it generates CodeStubAssembler-using C++ code), but this is mostly answered by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56857660/debugging-codestubassembler-csa-code-in-v8